# Why doesn't pycharm provide code completion for column name in script, while RStudio does?

Tags: python, r, pycharm, rstudio

I have a DataFrame `df` which columns [`my_column_1`, `my_column_2`, `my_column_3`].

In RStudio script: when I write `df.my_`, it suggest me with a dropdown menu containing all three columns.
Why the same thing does not work in pycharm.

Comment: Because they're totally different software. Kind of like how Microsoft Word does things that Google Docs doesn't, and vice versa, even though they're both word processors.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that PyCharm at present doesn't evaluate Pandas column and row indexes that are at run time.

Trying this in the editor and it definitely doesn't work, as you say, but in the iPython console once the dataframe exists, autocomplete does work as you would want. Not that that's very helpful.

There does seem to be a ticket marked as 'Ready to Release' that seems to be designed to fix the problem you highlighted: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33480